# Response Message passing between multiple Outbound gateway calls over Rest Api

Tags: spring-integration

I have one inbound gateway which receives messages over Rest. All messages recieved enter to Internal Gateway . Below is the inbound gateway xml file.

```
 <bean name="testConfig" class="test.TestApiConfiguration"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" supported-methods="POST" path="/data" reply-channel="replyChannel"
                              request-payload-type="com.test.model.CallFlow" header-mapper="cc20InBoundHeaders" error-channel="errorChannel" reply-timeout="9000">
        <int-http:request-mapping produces="application/json" consumes="application/json"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <bean id="cc20InBoundHeaders" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
        <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cc20OutBoundHeaders" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
        <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="Content-Type, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"/>
        <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
    </bean>
```

So, inbound gateway messages arrive as Json correctly and then an Internal Gateway accepts them and messages are passed into channels are per the configuration.

```
@MessagingGateway(name="callFlowGateway", requestChannel = "callFlowRequestChannel")
public interface ICallFlow {

    /**
     * Process CallFlow Request
     * @param message SI Message covering APiCall payload and relevant headers for service
     */
    @Gateway
    void processCallFlowRequest(Message<CallFlow> message);

}
```

Till here, it works as expected. Messages flow to Filter and then router. in Router, if type of one json property is "drink" service, then drink channel is invoked and relevant outbound gateways are called to request an external API endpoints over REST.

But before calling each of the rest endpoints of that external API, you need to have a valid session id token to access other endpoints.  It returns a session id in its payload to call other endpoints Beside that,  it takes application/x-www-form-urlencoded as content Type in header. 
I created a transformer to create request for authentication service.

```
@MessageEndpoint               
public class AuthenticateTransformer {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "splitterChannel", outputChannel = "authenticateRequestChannel")
    public Message<?> transform(CallFlow callFlow) {

        Map<String, Object> messagePayload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        messagePayload.put("user", "test");
        messagePayload.put("password", "test");
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagePayload).setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();
        }
}
```

So, ideally , a call comes to inbound gateway-
Json is converted to an internal object. Based on one property value in JSON, i call different external rest endpoints using http outbound gateway.

Since the call for authentication to get session id is not in Json that is received, i have to create an order in the flow.

1. I need to invoke an http outbound gateway for authentication to get that session id.  How can i invoke this outbound from inbound gateway because that should be executed before every call to other endpoint.
2. After i get that session id , then i want other endpoints over Rest, at this phase, i want ICallFlow gateway to be called , so that based on value in json, and that session id from step 1, i can call other rest endpoints and get response back.

So, i am stuck in passing that session id token from First call to the second call ?  plus i want ICallFlow only be invoked after first authentication request is complete , and pass that session into other subsequent requests. I read that header enricher can do that, where i can put payload into headers, but somehow its not working. Also, i am not sure how to create above flow in the right order.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You that's too much information in a single thread and it somehow confusing and misleading.

What I can suggest you is something like `ContentEnricher`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher

So, you will call that auth service via `request-channel` sub-flow, get a session id back and will be able to populate it into headers or that `ICallFlow` payload if that is possible.

you should be careful using `MessageBuilder` in the `@Transformer` use-case. That one doesn't merge request headers afterwards and you won't be able to bring a response to the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` in the beginning, just because the `replyChannel` header will be lost.

The way to carry request headers is like accept a `Message` in the `transform()` method and call `copyHeaders()` on the `MessageBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you Artem.  I agree that its too much information on same thread. Which part is confusing ?  how can i invoke outbound gateway ( which gets session id ) at the point when message (json )arrives in inbound gateway ?  When a message arrives in Inbound, it goes to internal gateway ICallFlow which has Message<CallFlow> message and message payload which is passed from first authenticated call is not CallFlow type. I hope i manage to explain the problem.

Comment: Well, let’s see first of all if my answer gives you some clues for your task!

Comment: I tried using it, and it works, but i am not using it because of the order of the calls in problem context.  I managed to write a simple http client implementation in bean which creates session token required at first invocation on inbound gateway. From there on, subsequest REST calls to external service happen.  As you said, you can lose message headers using transformers. I am using ServiceActivators for request construction message, which calls outbound gateway to access external service endpoints using Rest.  Service Activators may be overkill for each request construction i guess.

Comment: So, i manage to pass session token from one request to other by populating headers ( used httpclient, and from payload, populated session token ).  Now i have 4 Rest calls to external service for one functional use case. I think <int-chain can be a great to put 4 outbound gateway calls for one authentication service for instance, Also i have some questions about performance ? standard VS webFlux ? and i am wondering if i should  use reactive to have inbound gateway response times better ? Thank you again.

Comment: Good to hear you have a solution. All other your concerns deserve separate SO threads

Comment: I will post tomorrow. Thank, you again.

Comment: Artem, I have a question on same lines.

Comment: What does it mean? On what lines? Sorry, there are too much work around to manage and without a proper context I'm lost. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: 1. http-inbound gateway receive a message, we process different endpoints to get data ( for instance clientId ) internally via our internal session token id.  Now, User enters OrderId via web, message received via http-inbound gateway, now we need clientId which we got in first request call, and we dont want to call 4 services again to data. Is there a way in spring-integration to get access to data between different two requests-responses ? or i have to cache thta using redis or other implementations ?

Comment: Why HTTP session doesn't work for you? You can get access to it from the `http:inbound-gateway` and copy the value to the headers (if any): https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#_uri_template_variables_and_expressions. The `RequestContextHolder` can help you to get access to the HTTP session. Different SO story though?..